# Scrapy shell not allowing me to type

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm having some trouble with the scrapy shell at the moment. Whenever I try and type a command into it all these debug messages appear as i'm typing and I can't see what i'm writing. This is using VS Code and a virtual environment from Anaconda if thats helpful.  Any ideas what is up with it?

```
2020-07-27 12:44:49 [parso.python.diff] DEBUG: -> code[replace] old[1:1] new[1:1]
2020-07-27 12:44:49 [parso.python.diff] DEBUG: parse_part from 1 to 1 (to 0 in part parser)
2020-07-27 12:44:49 [parso.python.diff] DEBUG: diff parser end
2020-07-27 12:44:49 [parso.python.diff] DEBUG: diff parser start
2020-07-27 12:44:49 [parso.python.diff] DEBUG: line_lengths old: 1; new: 1
2020-07-27 12:44:49 [parso.python.diff] DEBUG: -> code[replace] old[1:1] new[1:1]
2020-07-27 12:44:49 [parso.python.diff] DEBUG: diff parser end
```

Comment: Use `-L INFO` in your `shell` command

Answer (score 0):

It bothers me for a long time, not found an ideal solution, after I uninstall parso module, all is well!

```
pip uninstall parso
```